# How to create a border layout in ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I am struggling using border layout in modern profile, but it only works in classic profile, anyone can give me some hint or example. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, I checked source code from src folder, looks no border layout for modern profile. I like border layout in classic profile, but also found an issue: splitter become ugly when I try collapse Navigation part and open again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See above issue related to splitter bar in border layout.

Answer (score -1):

You've answered it yourself in the comments. There is no Border layout in the modern profile, so you can't use it.